# Нейронные сети выдающие вероятность принадлежности элемента определенному классу

Tags: машинное-обучение

Видел примеры нейронных сетей которые могут определять что изображено на картинке с определенной вероятностью. Что за вид нейронных сетей или как получить вероятность того что элемент принадлежит определенному классу?

Comment: Для этого используются глубокие сверточные сети (CNN - Convolutional Neural Networks). Ответ на вопрос "как получить вероятность того что элемент принадлежит определенному классу", если отвечать на него понятно и с примерами займёт 15 - 20 печатных страниц. Это противоречит идеологии данного сайта - здесь отвечают на конкретные вопросы, которые возникли при реализации/кодировании/проектировании. Можно начать читать [отсюда](http://datareview.info/article/9-publikacij-kotorye-dolzhen-prochest-kazhdyj-specialist-po-ml-chast-2/)

Comment: Если я все правильно перевел, то мне подойдет преобразование SoftMax  на последнем слое https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265905/derivative-of-softmax-with-respect-to-weights